# ATtiny85 and MPU-6050 Gyroscope

Tags: serial, mpu6050, gyroscope, attiny85

I'm doing a project that involves sending MPU-6050 gyroscope data via serial communication to the laptop. Is ATtiny85 micro-controller suitable for this job? Is it powerful enough to do it? I was thinking of using an Arduino nano instead. please give me your opinion.

Comment: The attiny85 doesn't (really) support USB. So you'd need to add something like usb-to-serial converter. Just save yourself a lot of headache and just use a Nano.